# Ethers.js create child wallet from parent wallet

Tags: ethers.js

i create wallet using ethers.js and get publickey,privatekey and Mnemonic. how can i create subwallets from above wallet. and how to get the private of the child wallets from the private wallet of the parent and the publickey of the child wallet

```
 const { ethers } = require('ethers');
 const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
 console.log(wallet.mnemonic);
 console.log(wallet.privateKey);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the function `ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic, path)`. You would pass in the mnemonic from the `wallet` you created, as well as the path. The path for the default (i.e. at the `0`th index) is `m/44’/60’/0’/0/0` (this is what you should have in your `wallet`.) The path for the next accounts would be `m/44'/60'/1'/0/0`, `m/44'/60'/2'/0/0`, etc. Passing these to the `fromMnemonic` function will create your further child wallets

This information can be found at https://docs.ethers.org/v4/api-wallet.html